# redirect the users to default page (no login) if user navigates to the page directly by typing the URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net, navigation, master-pages, response.redirect

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 intranet website which has a default page with a menu and when the user clicks on a menu item, I display the page for that menu item in an iframe embedded within the default page. but if the user types the URL of a page directly in the browser, then I would like to redirect him to the default page, because all the content pages do not have a menu. (Master Pages will solve this issue, but I can't use Master page here for a reason and don't want to go into those details). how to find out if user has arrived at the page directly by typing the URL or by clicking on the menu item, so that I can decide whether to redirect or not? Is this possible to find out? btw this is an intranet site and no login is required. thanks in advance.

Comment: Why use an iframe to start with? Bad design. If you can not use a master page, than make the menus and other common components into user controls and add them to the page.

Comment: I am using a third party menu control which collapses to the root everytime I navigate to a different page if I use master pages. fixing the menu control to maintain the state isn't a trivial task and also I wanted to hide the actual page url. I can use URL routing for that but that complicates my simple application. so finally I decided to go with iframes. I don't think adding menu to every page as a user control is good. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use MasterPages for your problem, beacuse iFrames are not a good technique.
But, you could try it with a litte JavaScript-Snippet in the content pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (top == self)
  window.location = "/index.html";
</script>
```

You simply check, if the loaded page is identical to your iFrame. If this is true, then your iFrame is loaded directly.

Comment: this worked. thanks. all my content pages use a master page, so I put this code in the master page. however the master page does not have a menu. menu is in the default page which has an iframe and all the content pages displayed in iframe use a master page to centralize common functionality. this isn't a good design, but I chose this technique to fix the collapsing menu problem and hide URLs.

Answer (score 1):

put this in your frame (or frame master page):

```
<body onload="CheckTop()"></body>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function CheckTop()
     {
         if (window == window.top) window.location = //topurl, pilot page
     }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, both the answers are same and I can't mark both of them as answer.